# Oracle:Select result based on outside parameter true or false

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have following two tables TestCustomer and TestEmail.I would like to retrieve emailAddress,email_stat based on email_stat on  TestCustomer and outside boolean parameter "noFlag".If noFlag is "true" get all the email addresses from **TestEmail** table and  email_stat **TestCustomer** from associated with customer_id otherwise get only "A" ones.Any Help would be appreciated.

```
create table TestEmail(emai_id varchar(18),emailaddress varchar(20))

create table TestCustomer(customer_id varchar(18),emai_id varchar(18),email_stat char(1))

Insert Into TestEmail(emai_id,emailaddress)values('12345','abc@gmail.com');
Insert Into TestEmail(emai_id,emailaddress)values('123456','abcd@gmail.com');
Insert Into TestEmail(emai_id,emailaddress)values('123457','abcde@gmail.com');

Insert Into TestCustomer(customer_id,emai_id,email_stat)values('223459','12345','A');
Insert Into TestCustomer(customer_id,emai_id,email_stat)values('223458','123456','I');
Insert Into TestCustomer(customer_id,emai_id,email_stat)values('223459','123457','A');
```

**Expected Input:**

customer_id=223458 and noFlag='true'

**Expected Output**

[image]

**Expected Input:**

customer_id=223458 and noFlag='false'

**Expected Output**

Empty Result.

Answer (score 0):

Is what you're asking for a pl/sql code?
because I'm not familiar with a way to get an outside parameter inside sql query without pl\sql functionality...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Virtual column to mark as 'true' or 'false':

```
create table TestCustomer(customer_id varchar(18),emai_id varchar(18),email_stat char(1), noflag as (decode(email_stat,'I','true','false')));
```

**Query-1:**

```
select tc.customer_id, email_stat, te.emailaddress from TestCustomer tc join TestEmail te on tc.emai_id = te.emai_id where tc.customer_id=223458 and tc.noflag='true';
```

[image]

**Query-2:**

```
select tc.customer_id, email_stat, te.emailaddress from TestCustomer tc join TestEmail te on tc.emai_id = te.emai_id where tc.customer_id=223458 and tc.noflag='false';
```

[image]

**Demo:**
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6291bf905c3387ff07e0ff145013afee

**Alternative Solution:**

1. No change in table structure
2. Create a view with noflag column

> Database View:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vw_email AS
SELECT tc.customer_id,
       tc.email_stat,
       te.emailaddress,
       decode(tc.email_stat,'I','true','false') as noflag 
  FROM TestCustomer tc 
  JOIN TestEmail te on tc.emai_id = te.emai_id;
```

> Query:

```
SELECT customer_id, email_stat, emailaddress FROM vw_email WHERE customer_id=223458 AND noflag='true';
```

> Demo:

```
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4f4f7b16beb26a3bc986eec4213f5c6e
```

Comment: I have added a solution based on my understanding from the question. I can be completely wrong. Please let let me know if it is not your question, so that I will delete my post.

Comment: The noFlag parameter lives completely outside of tables comes from java.

Comment: Here is one more solution: `https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4f4f7b16beb26a3bc986eec4213f5c6e`

Comment: The java code should read from View having noflag column

Comment: @JohnDoe: Please consider voting up and accepting it if it solved the problem !